# TypeError: (0 , _lib_utils__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.cn) is not a function - I am trying to make a nextjs and react platform and it gives me this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, next.js, next.js13

```
src/components/MaxWidthWrapper.tsx (12:27) @ MaxWidthWrapper
 ⨯ TypeError: (0 , _lib_utils__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.cn) is not a function
    at MaxWidthWrapper (./src/components/MaxWidthWrapper.tsx:13:66)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "3255126488"
  10 | }) => {
  11 |     return(
> 12 |         <div className={cn('mx-auto w-full max-w-screen-xl px-2.5 md:px-20', className)}>
     |                           ^
  13 |             {children}
  14 |         </div>
  15 |     )
 ✓ Compiled /favicon.ico in 32ms (264 modules)
```

I have a page.tsx file that has this code:

```
import MaxWidthWrapper from "@/components/MaxWidthWrapper";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <MaxWidthWrapper className="mb-12 mt-28 sm:mt-40 flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-center">
      <div className="mx-auto mb-4 flex max-w-fit items-center justify-center space-x-2 overflow-hidden rounded-full border border-gray-200 bg-white px-7 py-2 shadow-md backdrop-blur transition-all hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-white/50">
        <p className="text-sm font-semibold dext-gray-700">
          GlobalFinanceFX is now public
        </p>
      </div>
    </MaxWidthWrapper>
  )
}
```

a utils.ts file that has a function that should be reused on all site to add equal spacing on right and left side.

```
import clsx, { ClassValue } from "clsx";
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";

export function cn(...inputs: ClassValue[]){
    return twMerge(clsx(inputs))
}
```

and this is the MaxWidthWrapper.tsx file where it says that there is a and that utils.ts is not a function:

```
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"
import { ReactNode } from "react"

const MaxWidthWrapper = ({
    className,
    children,
}: {
    className?: string
    children: ReactNode
}) => {
    return(
        <div className={cn('mx-auto w-full max-w-screen-xl px-2.5 md:px-20', className)}>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}

export default MaxWidthWrapper
```

and here are the folders with the files:
[Here are all the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIbg8.png)